# Alternatives to using nested functions in PySpark mapPartitions when using Cython?

Tags: python, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, cython

I have a row-wise operation I wish to perform on my dataframe which takes in some fixed variables as parameters. The only way I know how to do this is with the use of nested functions. I'm trying to use Cython to compile a portion of my code, then call the Cython function from within mapPartitions, but it raised the error `PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction outer_function.<locals>._nested_function at 0xfffffff>`.

When using pure Python, I do

```py
def outer_function(fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2):
    def _nested_function(partition):
        for row in partition:
            yield dosomething(row, fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2)
    return _nested_function

output_df = input_df.repartition(some_col).rdd \
    .mapPartitions(outer_function(a, b))
```

Right now I have `outer_function` defined in a separate file, like this

```py
# outer_func.pyx

def outer_function(fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2):
    def _nested_function(partition):
        for row in partition:
            yield dosomething(row, fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2)
    return _nested_function
```

and this

```py
# runner.py

from outer_func import outer_function

output_df = input_df.repartition(some_col).rdd \
    .mapPartitions(outer_function(a, b))
```

And this throws the pickling error above.

I've looked at https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/faq/cython.html and tried to get `outer_function`. Still, the same error occurs. The problem is that the nested function does not appear in the global space of the module, thus it cannot be found and serialized.

I've also tried doing this

```py
def outer_function(fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2):
    global _nested_function
    def _nested_function(partition):
        for row in partition:
            yield dosomething(row, fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2)
    return _nested_function
```

This throws a different error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_nested_function'`.

Is there any way of not using nested function in this case? Or is there another way I can make the nested function "serializable"?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I also tried doing

```py
# outer_func.pyx

class PartitionFuncs:

    def __init__(self, fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2):
        self.fixed_var_1 = fixed_var_1
        self.fixed_var_2 = fixed_var_2

    def nested_func(self, partition):
        for row in partition:
            yield dosomething(row, self.fixed_var_1, self.fixed_var_2)
```

```
# main.py

from outer_func import PartitionFuncs

p_funcs = PartitionFuncs(a, b)
output_df = input_df.repartition(some_col).rdd \
    .mapPartitions(p_funcs.nested_func)
```

And still I get `PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction PartitionFuncs.nested_func at 0xfffffff>`. Oh well, the idea didn't work.

Comment: It may depend what `fixed_var_1` and `fixed_var_2` are and if they're pickleable. When I try with your code and a string and int it seems fine. (My other suggestion would be that if you can pickle `p_funcs` but not `p_funcs.nested_func`, then give `PartitionFuncs` a `__call__` method)

Comment: Just to clarify the above - I tried the "class" version. I don't think nested functions are pickleable

Comment: @DavidW I tested out the code using the "class" method and it says `PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction PartitionFuncs.nested_func at 0xfffffff>`. All my variables are strings.

Comment: @DavidW I tried out your suggestion to give `PartitionFuncs` a `__call__` method and it worked perfectly! I'll need to define a new class for each method, but that's not an issue. In any case, do you want to post the suggestion as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sort-of-half answer because when I tried your `class PartitionFuncs` method `p_funcs.nested_func` pickled/unpickled fine for me (I didn't try combining it with PySpark though), so whether the solution below is necessary may depend on your Python version/platform etc. Pickle [should support bound methods from Python 3.4](https://bugs.python.org/issue9276), however it looks like PySpark [forces the pickle protocol to 3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/serializers.html), which will stop that working. There might be ways to change this but I don't know them.

Nested functions are known not to be pickleable, so that approach definitely work work. The class approach is the right one.

My suggestion in the comments was to just try pickling the class, not the bound function. For this to work an instance of the class needs to be callable, so you rename your function to `__call__`

```
class PartitionFuncs:
    def __init__(self, fixed_var_1, fixed_var_2):
        self.fixed_var_1 = fixed_var_1
        self.fixed_var_2 = fixed_var_2

    def __call__(self, partition):
        for row in partition:
            yield dosomething(row, self.fixed_var_1, self.fixed_var_2)
```

This does depend on both the `fixed_var` variables being pickleable by default. If they're not you can write [custom saving and loading methods, as described in the pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances).

As you point out in your comment, this does mean you need a separate class for each function you define. Options here involve inheritance, so having a separate `PickleableData` class, that each of the `Func` classes can hold a reference to.